# How do I prevent a page and tab's document.title from changing?

Tags: javascript, web

Some pages change their `document.title`, which appears in the page's tab, when certain events occur. It can be confusing to have a tab with ever-changing names, so I want to prevent it from changing. How to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use javascript to define a property on the `document` object with name `title` and a non-functional setter.

```
Object.defineProperty(document, 'title', {
  set: function(){}
});
```

You could execute this in the Developer console, put it in the address bar as a single line prepended by "javascript:", or you could put it in a user script or extension if you want it to be executed every time.